# How to Transfer 100GB database from GCP to AWS

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a 100GB database hosted in GCP's Cloud SQL offering in us-east1
I'd like to transfer this to AWS lightsail databases and hosted in AP-SOUTHEAST-2.

Within AWS I'm using AWS Lightsail Databases which do not support loading from S3.

What is the recommended way to transfer a database of this size across clouds and regions?